# How to parse string with ENTER into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am receiving the following string from the backend:

> Hello world : ↵ My name is uksz↵ hello world - 
>   630,00  ↵

As you can see, the `↵` in the string is the symbol for ENTER. The above line should read as follows:

> Hello world : 
>  My name is uksz
>  hello world - 
>   630,00

Unfortunately, when I am trying to parse the string from javascript (angular2) to html, it is displayed in the following way:

> Hello world :  My name is uksz hello world - 630,00

What can I do, to ensure that ENTERS are displayed?

Comment: `str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User string replace on your function on your response :

```
strResponse.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
```

Above code will replace all `'\n'` and other chars with `<br>`.

Comment: As far as I understand regexp, it will replace all \n characters with '<br />'.

Comment: Yes. It will replace \n with <br>

Comment: Yes, and this is exactly what you need: replacing every "new line" as it is stored in your backend with a visible "line break" in HTML.

Comment: @Abhijeet, can you explain me why '<br />' instead of ''<br>' inside the replace function?

Comment: Simply <br> is sufficient.

The other forms are there for compatibility with XHTML; to make it possible to write the same code as XHTML, and have it also work as HTML. Some systems that generate HTML may be based on XML generators, and thus do not have the ability to output just a bare <br> tag; if you're using such a system, it's fine to use <br/>, it's just not necessary if you don't need to do it.

Comment: Simply for
HTML : <br>,

XHTML : <br/> or <br></br>